# How can I drag arrow which is created using two shapes a polygon and a line, using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, annotations, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have created arrow using the following code, and I'm able to draw this shape properly in the canvas. Since these are two different shapes I'm not able to drag or rotate the arrow.

```
    activateArrow = () => {
        if (this.arrowButtonClicked === false) {
            this.canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
            this.canvas.on('mouse:down', this.startAddingArrow);
            this.canvas.on('mouse:move', this.startDrawingArrow);
            this.canvas.on('mouse:up', this.stopDrawingArrow);
        }
    };

    startAddingArrow = (o) => {
            this.mouseDown = true;
            let pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(o.e);

            this.line = new fabric.Line(
                [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y],
                {
                    id: 'arrow-line',
                    stroke: this.color,
                    strokeWidth: this.stroke,
                    selectable: true,
                    hasControls: true,
                }
            );

            this.arrowHead = new fabric.Polygon(
                [
                    { x: 0, y: 0 },
                    { x: -20, y: -10 },
                    { x: -20, y: 10 },
                ],
                {
                    id: 'arrow-head',
                    stroke: this.color,
                    fill: this.color,
                    strokeWidth: this.stroke,
                    selectable: true,
                    hasControls: true,
                    top: pointer.y,
                    left: pointer.x,
                    originX: 'center',
                    originY: 'center',
                }
            );

            this.canvas.add(this.line, this.arrowHead);
        
    };

    startDrawingArrow = (o) => {
            if (this.mouseDown === true) {
                let pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(o.e);

                this.line.set({
                    x2: pointer.x,
                    y2: pointer.y,
                });

                this.arrowHead.set({
                    top: pointer.y,
                    left: pointer.x,
                });

                let x1 = this.line.x1;
                let y1 = this.line.y1;
                let x2 = pointer.x;
                let y2 = pointer.y;

                let verticalHeight = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
                let horizontalWidth = Math.abs(x2 - x1);

                let tan = verticalHeight / horizontalWidth;
                let basicAngle = (Math.atan(tan) * 180) / Math.PI;

                if (x2 > x1) {
                    if (y2 < y1) {
                        this.arrowHead.set({
                            angle: -basicAngle,
                        });
                    } else if (y2 === y1) {
                        this.arrowHead.set({
                            angle: 0,
                        });
                    } else if (y2 > y1) {
                        this.arrowHead.set({
                            angle: basicAngle,
                        });
                    }
                } else if (x2 < x1) {
                    if (y2 > y1) {
                        this.arrowHead.set({
                            angle: 180 - basicAngle,
                        });
                    } else if (y2 === y1) {
                        this.arrowHead.set({
                            angle: 180,
                        });
                    } else if (y2 < y1) {
                        this.arrowHead.set({
                            angle: 180 + basicAngle,
                        });
                    }
                }

                this.line.setCoords();
                this.arrowHead.setCoords();

                this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
            }
        
    };

    stopDrawingArrow = () => {
      this.mouseDown = false;
    };
```

I have tried to group line and polygon but it didn't work as expected. I was expecting to drag/move the whole shape together, rotate and resize it.